# SPNEGO troubles for users with many groups (memberOf)

Tags: tomcat, kerberos, spnego

We install tomcat 7.0.56+spnego_r7 (+nginx proxy) on linux (RHEL), jdk 8_20. Its works fine in servlet - request.getUserPrincipal().
All work good only for users (AD) with few groups (2-3 memberOf).

For users with many groups we received in browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox) “ERR::UNEXPECTED”: provisional headers are shown.
Logs is empty, but we activate:

```
-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true -Dsun.security.spnego.debug=all
```

And

```
<init-param>
<param-name>spnego.logger.level</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</init-param>
```

But logs show only successful auths. No errors.

We increase buffers, headers in nginx and tomcat to 64k (and to 1m for experiment, but go back), MaxTokenSize in Windows registry…. And don’t work.
Try another version of tomcat, jdk and its not help.

How we can get successful through pass auth for users with many groups (memberOf)?

Comment: Does the client actually generate a token? If yes, how big is the Base 64 value? How many groups does this user have? You need to reduce the data in the PAC probably.

Comment: Problem was solved when we changed KDC from *.ur.rt.ru to *.ks.rt.ru. And now all it works. Admin of kdc ur.rt.ru can't say what is wrong with their KDC.